# Magento Free shipping and Discount Coupon

Tags: php, magento

I use Shopping cart price rule to set Free shipping for orders above 700$.

However when a Discount Coupon is applied & the subtotal falls below 700$, free Shipping is enabled. How could I make Free Shipping check to calculate price using the price after applying the discount & not with the subtotal ?

In Magento Shopping cart rule, is there somehow we can create a rule based on the total (Including the discount) instead of subtotal ?

Magento version : 1.7.0.2 CE

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible out of the box. What you need in your case is an additional cart rule condition.
To achieve this you have to rewrite the core class `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Address` and extend the functions `loadAttributeOptions` and `validate`.